# known services to validate csv file

Tags: validation, service, csv, web

Are there any good **sites/services** to validate consistency of CSV file ?

The same as  [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) but for CSV ?

Thanks!

Comment: Validate it against what? Is there a CSV spec somewhere? I've seen plenty of different, incompatible flavors myself.

Comment: @Eli: There's [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180), at least.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I recently came across [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) (now [OpenRefine](https://openrefine.org)) - it's not a service for validating CSV files, it's a tool you download locally, but it does provide a lot of tools for working with data and detecting anomalies.

As mentioned in a reply, "CSV" has become an ill-defined term, principally because people don't follow the One True Way when using delimiter separated data

[http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch05s02.html](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/ch05s02.html)

EDIT/UPDATE (2016-08-09):
[CSV Currently Becoming a Well-Defined Term by the W3C CSV Working Group](https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-primer/)

Comment: Getting a good definition of CSV is all very well - but given the majority of CSV data will continue to be i) Excel and ii) horrible old code ... I don't hold out a lot of hope that it will really make a difference. I would tend to advocate people use the One True Way linked above if they are creating new tabular data export routines...

Answer (score 13):

The Open Data Institute is developing a CSV validation service that will allow users to check the structure of their data as well as validate it against a simple schema.

The service is still very much in alpha but can be found here:

http://csvlint.io/

The code for the application and the underlying library are both open source:

https://github.com/theodi/csvlint

https://github.com/theodi/csvlint.rb

The README in the library provides a summary of the errors and warnings that can be generated. The following types of error can be reported:

- `:wrong_content_type` -- content type is not text/csv
- `:ragged_rows` -- row has a different number of columns (than the first row in the file)
- `:blank_rows` -- completely empty row, e.g. blank line or a line where all column values are empty
- `:invalid_encoding` -- encoding error when parsing row, e.g. because of invalid characters
- `:not_found` -- HTTP 404 error when retrieving the data
- `:quoting` -- problem with quoting, e.g. missing or stray quote, unclosed quoted field
- `:whitespace` -- a quoted column has leading or trailing whitespace

The following types of warning can be reported:

- `:no_encoding` -- the Content-Type header returned in the HTTP request does not have a charset parameter
- `:encoding` -- the character set is not UTF-8
- `:no_content_type` -- file is being served without a Content-Type header
- `:excel` -- no Content-Type header and the file extension is .xls
- `:check_options` -- CSV file appears to contain only a single column
- `:inconsistent_values` -- inconsistent values in the same column. Reported if <90% of values seem to have same data type (either numeric or alphanumeric including punctuation)

Comment: This service reports total garbage without a schema. Not used with schema though.

Answer (score 2):

The National Archives developed a [CSV Schema Language](http://digital-preservation.github.io/csv-schema/) and [CSV Validator](http://digital-preservation.github.io/csv-validator/), software written in Java. It's open source.

Answer (score 1):

To validate a CSV file I use the RAINBOW CSV extension in Visual Studio Code and also I open the CSV file in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great way to validate your CSV file.I am referring to this [article](https://blog.openbridge.com/how-to-do-csv-file-validation-and-schema-generation-43a9cb78e1eb), where the whole process is explained in tiniest details.

The validation process has two steps: the first one is to post the file to the API. Once your file is accepted,the API returns a polling endpoint that contains the results of the validation process.10 MB limit per file.

Answer (score 0):

[CSV Lint](https://csvlint.com/) at csvlint.com (not .io :) is a service we're building to solve this problem. It checks CSV files against user-defined validation rules / schemas cell by cell.

We spent a lot of time tweaking the UI to allow users to create complex validation rules / schemas easily that meet their business needs without a single line of code.

Our offline validation feature allows users to see the results in-realtime even when validating multiple large size (with millions+ rows) files, and most importantly it 100% protects user data privacy.

Comment: The service reports wrong number of rows in CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

[Toolkit Bay CSV Validator & Linter](https://toolkitbay.com/tkb/tool/csv-validator) online, easy to use, set delimiter and go.

[Flatfile CSV validator](https://try.flatfile.io/csv-validator-for-web-apps) online demo, automatic delimiter detection, upload and go.