# Check if the file is a valid CSV file

Tags: php, validation, csv, unicode

I have a CSV file, which is converted from a UNICODE to CSV file. I did this to process UTF-8 character. So here is the problem, I have a CSV file but when I tried to upload it, seems like it is not accepted as a CSV file.  The csv file is somewhat read as a UNICODE from it's origin. When I used this condition to validate the file, it is bypass and generate an error, This condition works just fine on other instances.

```
 $mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
 if( !empty($_FILES['csv_attach']['tmp_name']) && in_array($_FILES['csv_attach']['type'],$mimes))
{
                          /* some codes */
}
```

Now the question is that, how can you validate if the file is a valid CSV file, not a UNICODE text file? Or how can you validate if the file is a UNICODE TEXT? That's what I am thinking for the solution, just to validate the file if it is a UNICODE text or not. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Unicode is standard of encoding text.

Mime types, like `text/csv` are a method of conveying what is in a file.

You're mixing up two ideas here and your question makes no sense.

There is no official standard for CSV files, though [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) might help.

There might be services that can validate the content of your CSV as discussed in this question: [known services to validate csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738996/are-there-known-services-to-validate-a-csv-file)