# How to validate a csv file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, csv

I have a large csv file that I need to convert to json, and then store the data into neo4j. I am using the csv-parser plugin for node.js. This works fine if the csv is valid. However if it's not valid, then the data in neo4j gets scrambled. Therefore I need to validate the file, before I can send it into my database. Are there any existing plugins available or is there a way for me to validate the csv file myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might look into checking out the API for [csvlint](http://csvlint.io/)

I also suggest checking out this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6837548/6437335). (Below this answer also has good csvlint info, too)

There is also [fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) which has some validation built in, which may help depending on your needs.

Otherwise, finding a validator that caters to your specific needs may be difficult, and I suggest writing editing your node script to validate it for yourself.

---

Update: I would also like to recommend [Papa Parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse), which has several parsing options.

Comment: Yes, I have already looked at csvlint and the other thread you mention. I thought there may be other available solutions. Thanks for the reply anyways.

Comment: edited in another solution, may or may not be of use. It might help if you posted some examples of exactly what you need, since there may not be a one size fits all solution. Good luck!